# How Do I Find Common Dates in Two Ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range, date-range

I have 2 date ranges, `start_date1..end_date1` and `start_date2..end_date2`, is there an easy "ruby" way to find all the dates that are in both ranges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(start_date1..end_date1).to_set & (start_date2..end_date2).to_set
```

here's a fully worked example:

```
require 'date'
require 'set'
((Date.today - 3)..(Date.today + 2)).to_set & (Date.today..(Date.today + 5)).to_set
```

if you're counting characters, you can also just do

```
(start_date1..end_date1).to_set & start_date2..end_date2
```

but I think the original version is clearer.

Comment: Using `to_a` instead of `to_set` will be a bit faster and should yield the same result.